# register_post_type not working in wordpress 3.6

Tags: actions

I am using WP3.6 and am having trouble adding a new post type. I have put echo statements in the code and know that

a) the function calling register_post_type gets called
b) the post type name i am using does not exist
c) register_post_type returns an object with all the values I specified

But at the end of it all, nothing happens. No UI is added. Nothing seems to gets registered. Below is my entire code:

```
function responsive_custom_init_as() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
    'new_item' => 'New Product',
    'all_items' => 'All Products',
    'view_item' => 'View Product',
    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
    'not_found' =>  'No products found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No products found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Products'
  );

  $args = array(
    'label' => 'Products',
    'labels' => $labels,
    'description' => 'Products imported from 1shoppingcart.com',
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => 'product',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false ),
    'capability_type' => array('onesc_product', 'onesc_products'),
    'capabilities' => array('edit_onesc_products' => false, 'publish_onesc_products' => true, 'read_private_onesc_products' => true),
    'has_archive' => false, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_onesc_meta_boxes_as'
  ); 

  register_post_type('onesc_product', $args);
}

function add_onesc_meta_boxes_as() {
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_id', 'Id'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_visibleid','Visible Id'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_sku', 'SKU'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_price', 'Price'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_isfeatured', 'Is Featured', 'checkbox'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_usesaleprice', 'Use Sale Price', 'checkbox'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_saleprice', 'Sale Price'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_isactive', 'Is Active', 'checkbox'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_hairtype', 'Hair Type'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_length', 'Length'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_style', 'Style'));
  add_meta_box('1sc_product_details', 'Product Details', 'responsive_add_field_as', 'onesc_product', 'normal', 'default', array('1sc_color', 'Color'));
}

function responsive_add_field_as($post, $customid, $customlbl, $type='text'){
  $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $customid, true);
  echo '<label for="'.$customid.'">'.$customlbl.'</label> ';
  echo '<input type="'.$type.'" id="'.$customid.'" name="'.$customid.'" value="'.esc_attr($value).'" size="25" />';
}

add_action( 'init', 'responsive_custom_init_as' );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I changed 'capability_type' to 'post' and it started working